# How to get value from nested group in reactive form?

Tags: angular, jhipster

I want to get the user values in a nested group in a reactive form. I don't succeed. 
I am using JHipster 6.2.0.

editForm is initialized at the beginning.

The updateForm is called on init.

The method createFromForm() is the one called upon saving.

The form initialize properly, and the values of user are correct in the front. However, upon saving, the user value is null, the object is not created.

I think that the method createFromForm() is not good, in the way that I don't create a user. However, I don't find the syntax to create it properly.

```
  editForm = this.fb.group({
id: [null],
activated: [],
user: this.fb.group({
  login: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.pattern('^[_.@A-Za-z0-9-]*')]],
  firstName: ['', [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  lastName: ['', [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  email: ['', [Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(254), Validators.email]],
  activated: [true],
})
  });


 updateForm(professional: IProfessional) {
this.editForm.patchValue({
  id: professional.id,
  activated: professional.activated,
  user: {
    login : professional.user.login,
    firstName: professional.user.firstName,
    lastName: professional.user.lastName,
    email: professional.user.email,
    activated: professional.user.activated
  }
});
  }

 private createFromForm(): IProfessional {
return {
  ...new Professional(),
  id: this.editForm.get(['id']).value,
  activated: this.editForm.get(['activated']).value,
  companyId: this.editForm.get(['companyId']).value,
  ...new User(),
    login : this.editForm.get(['user.login']).value,
    firstName : this.editForm.get(['user.firstName']).value,
    lastName : this.editForm.get(['user.lastName']).value,
    email : this.editForm.get(['user.email']).value,
    activated : this.editForm.get(['user.activated']).value
  }
};
```

}

To note, the professional model ts is:

```
import {IUser} from "../../core/user/user.model";
export interface IProfessional {
  id?: number;
  activated?: boolean;
  user?: IUser;
}

export class Professional implements IProfessional {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public activated?: boolean,
    public user?: IUser
  ) {
    this.activated = this.activated || false;
  }
}
```

The template form:

```
<form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="editForm">
        <h2 id="jhi-professional-heading" jhiTranslate="ormaxwebApp.professional.home.createOrEditLabel">Create or edit a Professional</h2>
        <div>
            <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>
            <div class="form-group" [hidden]="!editForm.get('id').value">
                <label for="id" jhiTranslate="global.field.id">ID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" formControlName="id"
                    readonly />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="ormaxwebApp.professional.activated" for="field_activated">Activated</label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="activated" id="field_activated"
                       formControlName="activated"/>
            </div>
            <div formGroupName="user">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="userManagement.login">Login</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login"
                           formControlName="login">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="userManagement.firstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName"
                           formControlName="firstName">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label jhiTranslate="userManagement.lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName"
                           formControlName="lastName">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="userManagement.email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" formControlName="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="activated">
                        <input class="form-check-input" [disabled]="id === null" type="checkbox" id="activated" name="activated"  formControlName="activated">
                        <span jhiTranslate="userManagement.activated">Activated</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" id="cancel-save" class="btn btn-secondary"  (click)="previousState()">
                <fa-icon [icon]="'ban'"></fa-icon>&nbsp;<span jhiTranslate="entity.action.cancel">Cancel</span>
            </button>
            <button type="submit" id="save-entity" [disabled]="editForm.invalid || isSaving" class="btn btn-primary">
                <fa-icon [icon]="'save'"></fa-icon>&nbsp;<span jhiTranslate="entity.action.save">Save</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**TRY without Brackets** not working

```
 private createFromForm(): IProfessional {
return {
  ...new Professional(),
  id: this.editForm.get('id').value,
  activated: this.editForm.get('activated').value,
  companyId: this.editForm.get('companyId').value,
  ...new User(),
    login : this.editForm.get('user.login').value,
    firstName : this.editForm.get('user.firstName').value,
    lastName : this.editForm.get('user.lastName').value,
    email : this.editForm.get('user.email').value,
    activated : this.editForm.get('user.activated').value
  }
};
```

I'm probably missing something but I don't get it.

Could you help me, please?

Thanks,

Manuela

Comment: you can get the value of the whole form with `this.editForm.value` instead of trying to construct the value manually in `createFromForm()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `createFromForm()` method you can simply use `this.editForm.value` instead of trying to construct the model from scratch.

If you want to manually construct the model you need access the nested group with a dot notated string

```
this.editForm.get('user.login').value
```

or a string array

```
this.editForm.get(['user', 'login']).value
```

Comment: Thanks. To use "this.editForm.value" is working. However, the manual construction, even with dot notated string, that I already used in createFromForm(), is not. Do you know what is my mistake? Also, if it is as simple as use this edit form value, do you know why the jhipster team prefered to use the createFromFrom() method? It's an auto-generated one. Thanks.

Comment: The way you were using was passing an array with a single dot notated string instead of just the dot notated string.  Remove the array brackets and it should work.  As for the use of `createFromForm()`, I'm not familiar with JHister but I'm assuming its created for cases where you may need to transform the form value into a different data type/model/strict typing before submitting it.

Comment: Ok. I tried. Even after removing the array brackets it's not working.